# Does the suspension spectrum functor preserve weak equivalences?

Tags: gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

Let $\Sigma^{\infty}$ denote the suspension spectrum functor from pointed topological spaces (=CGWH spaces) to orthogonal spectra. As usual, a weak equivalence of spaces is a continuous map inducing a bijection on $\pi_0$ and an iso on all $\pi_i$, $i\ge 1$, for all choices of basepoint. For orthogonal spectra, I refer to the usual notion of stable equivalence, see e.g. Mandell-May-Shipley-Schwede.

**Question:** If $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ is a weak equivalence, is $\Sigma^\infty f\colon \Sigma^\infty X\longrightarrow \Sigma^\infty Y$ a stable equivalence?

**Remarks:** 1. This is true if $X$ and $Y$ are well-pointed, see [this MO discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108930/smashing-with-a-cw-complex-preserves-weak-equivalences-between-well-pointed-spac/108996#108996).

2. In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are not well-pointed, then the reduced suspension does not preserve weak equivalences. For example, take the set $\{0\} \cup\{\frac 1n\}$ which receives a weak equivalence from a countable discrete set. The reduced suspension is a map from a wedge of spheres to the Hawaiian earrings which is not a weak equivalence.

Comment: Doesn't your counterexample in $2$ answer this in the negative if $X,Y$ are not well-pointed?

Comment: @Tyrone: it is not clear to me whether the map becomes a weak equivalence after suspending further

Comment: Enough of the homology of the Hawaiian earing is known and is not the homology of the wedge. In fact $\pi_n$ of the $n$-dimensional Hawaiian earing is known (and it is not even free abelian if I recall).

Comment: Hmm you are right about the homology, but I think this argument uses the suspension iso for reduced suspension and reduced homology implicitely and this does NOT hold for not-well-pointed spaces (since the reduced cone is not acyclic, at least I don't see why it should be).

Comment: Or did you intend to argue in another way?

Comment: What do you mean by acyclic here? If you don't want to use homology, then just use the computation of $\pi_n$ of the $n$-dimensional Hawaiian Earing (which the the $(n-1)$-fold reduced suspension of the Hawaiian Earing).

Comment: This sounds good, didn't know the computation about the n-dimensional HE

Comment: @Tyrone if you write this as an answer I will accept it :)